# Read CSV file to numpy array, first row as strings, rest as float

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have data stored in a CSV where the first row is strings (column names) and the remaining rows are numbers.  How do I store this to a numpy array?  All I can find is how to set data type for columns but not for rows.

Right now I'm just skipping the headers to do the calculations but I need to have the headers in the final version.  But if I leave the headers in it sets the whole array as string and the calculations fail.

This is what I have:

```
 data = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv, dtype=None, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can keep the column names if you use the `names=True` argument in the function `np.genfromtxt`

```
 data = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

Please note the `dtype=float`, that will convert your data to float. This is more efficient than using `dtype=None`, that asks `np.genfromtxt` to guess the datatype for you.

The output will be a structured array, where you can access individual columns by their name. The names will be taken from your first row. Some modifications may occur, spaces in a column name will be changed to `_` for example. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) should cover most questions you could have.

Comment: I did it this way but it made an array with no columns.  Just stored the whole row in one column

Comment: What did you do *exactly*? What's your traceback?

Comment: I did exactly your above line of code.  I dont know what traceback is.

Comment: Then, could you pastebin a portion of your input file, so that we can try? The "whole row in one column" looks fairly strange to me... The traceback is a copy of the screen you get after executing the code (when it fails).

Comment: heres the pastebin from the interpreter just using the genfromtxt and the first two rows of the resulting matrix. You can see the data is stored only in rows and no columns. I did a .shape at the end.  http://bpaste.net/show/45175/

Comment: Well, the shape of your array is `(750,)`, meaning you have 750 different rows, each row consisting of about 20 individual fields. You could access each field by its name: you can find the name in the `dtype` of your array.

Comment: oh ok didn't know you had to access columns by the dtype.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just one note: Names like `-1` are stripped of the minus (and if there is also a `1`, one of both becomes `1_1`), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29097917/321973)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you need the headers in the final version, but you can generate a structured array where the columns are accessed by strings like this:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

and then access columns with `data['col1_name']`, `data['col2_name']`, etc.

Comment: You can also get the column names with `data.dtype.names` if you need to access them.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of a numpy array is that all elements are the same type. Read the headers into a Python list and manage them separately from the numbers. You can also create a structured array (an array of records) and in this case you can use the headers to name the fields in the records. Storing them in the array would be redundant in that case.

Comment: but the genfromtxt function stores the data into a ndarray and allows for the option to choose the data type for each column.  If there were a way to do this by rows, I would be set.  My calculating functions extract the numbers into another array.  If I could get to keep the headers, I would be able to label my outputs.

Comment: But you *can* keep the headers, you just can't store them directly in the array. So, go ahead and do that. Having them stored in the array will be more of a hindrance than a help.

Comment: so if i understand your method, you're saying to declare an array of structs where each struct contains the name and a dynamic array to hold the numbers?

Comment: user545424's answer is more along the lines of what I was thinking.