# How to preserve column names starting with a minus when using numpy.genfromtxt?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, numpy

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16020137/321973), `numpy.genfromtxt` modifies my columns' names:

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970414/321973

str = 'x,-1,1\n0,1,1\n1,2,3'
data = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(str.encode()), delimiter=',', names=True)
print(data.dtype.names)
```

yields `('x', '1', '1_1')` instead of the desired `('x', '-1', '1')` (or even better, `('x', -1, 1)`). I tried `deletechars="""~!@#$%^&*()=+~\|]}[{';: /?>,<"""` as suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16021059/321973) to no avail.

Comment: I think the column names have to be valid identifiers, which `-1` isn't.

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to obtain a `np.meshgrid` by the way, so please go ahead and stop me from an XY-Problem ;)

Comment: @jonrsharpe You mean not all strings are valid? Is there a list of valid identifiers?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: but those are python identifiers, can't the `dtype.names` be any string just like a `dict` can be constructed as `dict('-1': -1, '1': 1)`?

Comment: I'm not certain, but [this doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) notes *"the “name” which must be a valid Python identifier"*

Comment: I see, thanks. I wonder why... Anyway, that makes my question rather inanswerable :/

Comment: Presumably so you can access by attribute, or for some internal implementation reasons. And yes; it does, rather!

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, they don't need to be valid identifiers: `x = np.array((1,), dtype=[('-1', 'i')]); x['-1']` works perfectly fine

Comment: @ali_m in that case, I'm stumped.

Comment: The reason why field names are 'mangled' is that you could ask for your structured array to be transformed into a [recarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) (where fields can be accessed as attributes). Such behavior would obviously fail if there's a non-alphanumerical character in your field name. Hence the preparsing by `NameValidator`.

Comment: @PierreGM Those are *still* legal field names for a `recarray`! The dot-indexing syntax of course won't work, but `dict`-style indexing is fine: `x.view(np.recarray)['-1']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is caused by the fact that `np.genfromtxt` uses the `NameValidator` class [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/_iotools.py#L303) to automatically strip certain non-alphanumeric characters from the field names.

It's perfectly legal for a field name to contain a `'-'` character, e.g.:

```
x = np.array((1,), dtype=[('-1', 'i')])
print(x['-1'])
# 1
```

In fact, two out of three of the modified field names you get back from `np.genfromtxt` are also not "valid Python identifiers" (`'1'` and `'1_1'`, since they start with digits).

It's therefore possible to construct the array you describe as long as you bypass using `np.genfromtxt` to set the field names. One way to do it would be to initialize an empty array, specify the field names and dtypes explicitly, then fill it with the rest of the string contents:

```
names = str.splitlines()[0].split(',')
types = ('i',) * 3
dtype = zip(names, types)

data = np.empty(2, dtype=dtype)
data[:] = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(str.encode()), delimiter=',', dtype=dtype,
                        skiprows=1)
print(repr(data))
# array([(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2)], 
#       dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('-1', '<i4'), ('1', '<i4')])
```

However, just because you can doesn't mean you should - there may well be other unpredictable consequences to having a `'-'` in one of your field names. The safest option is to stick with using only valid Python identifiers as field names.