# Turn CSV values into numpy array with fileds as array indices

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a CSV file of 625 rows like this-

```
X_coordinate,Y_coordinate,Value
0,0,10
0,1,6
0,2,7
.
.
1,0,11
1,1,9
1,2,3
.
.
24,23,3
24,24,12
```

I want to convert this file into a numpy array of 25*25, where array indices contain corresponding values from CSV like-

```
[[10 6 7....]
 [11 9 3....]
 .
 .
 .
 [......3 12]]
```

How can I go about scripting this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't just do it for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the column names if you use the names=True argument in np.genfromxt. Following code assumes the Value is int:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv, dtype=int, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

[Read CSV file to numpy array, first row as strings, rest as float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336234/read-csv-file-to-numpy-array-first-row-as-strings-rest-as-float)

Then, assign a values for each pair of indices.

```
m = np.zeros((25, 25))
for x, y, value in data:
    m[x, y] = value
```